How to prepare a natural gas stub from crawl space through unfinished exterior wall
The exterior wall to my patio is currently gutted due to a water leak. The cripple wall to the crawlspace only has plywood and will get water barrier, stucco coats and paint soon.
It has always been my desire to have a natural gas stub for connecting my BBQ directly on the patio. There is an existing gas line in the crawl space, about 20 ft away.
Connecting a gas line is not something I want to do all by myself but since the wall is open, I would at least like to run the pipe through the plywood (where it would then get properly waterproofed) and ideally run next to the existing gas line. But adding a Tee to the existing line and possibly adding the stub outside, I would like to leave to a professional in the future.
What is the best way to prepare for this gas stub to minimize the cost for connecting it?
Some things to consider:

Which pipe is best? Black steel pipe?
Which diameter should I pick? 3/4" or 1/2" or something else?
Which length should I put through the plywood? For example, this 3/4" x 10ft pipe?
How should I best attach the pipe in the crawl space? Are normal straps like these ok and screw on joists?


All these questions depend on the properties and conditions of the existing materials. Are the existing pipes black iron? What is the diameter of the existing pipe? What are the distances and geometry of your plumbing and the location of the proposed gas grill? Pictures and/or diagrams would help.
